# Sharing an Access database in the network and connect it from several C# applications

Tags: c#, ms-access, sharing

I want to share an Access database in the local network (by sharing a folder in the Windows that contains the database).

I want to write an application (C# windows form) that open the shared database then selects, updates and deletes some records.

Several instance of my application will be running in the network (from various computers) and all the instances open the same database.

Does changing an Access database from various computers in the network possible?

**Note**: I don't want to use SQL SERVER or SQL SERVER EXPRESS, because all the computers in the network are too old and too slow for installing SQL SERVER. Installing and supporting SQL SERVER or SQL SERVER EXPRESS are hard too.

Comment: You don't need to install sql server on every client machine, only on server. If you are using .net all libraries (refereing to System.Data.SqlClient) are already included in framework that will need to be installed to run your program on client machine. I would strongly suggest you to use sql server instead access database anyway.

Answer (score 1):

First must Add `Mode=Share Deny None`(This will open your database file in full share mode) to connection string for Accessing multiple user,after this you can do this two ways:

1. share original app with data base in server and add it's folder as
   virtual drive in other system.
2. make 3 copy in each system and put DB in server,share it and
   change connection string to server

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ODCB driver you can simply give the shared folder on your network and let it use your database and you can run it on all systems